# Declaration of const in es6

Tags: constants, ecmascript-6

`"abc"` is read-only while parsing file:

```
export const abc = 20;
abc = 30; // Reassigning the value
```

Will this fail across all browsers?

Comment: If the browser [supports ES6 const](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-const), yes it should.

Comment: What do you mean with "fail"? That the variable value is not updated? Or that an error is thrown?

Comment: @FelixKling I mean will it throw an error? Chrome and Mozilla do throw an error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will fail (with a syntax error), as no browsers do yet support modules.

Comment: I have tried working on this, if "use strict" is used, const is supported but re assigning a value to it is not possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found out the answer. Browsers do throw error if we try to change the value of a const and they don't allow to rewrite. But safari doesn't handle this, it doesn't throws any error.

Answer (score 0):

If the browsers are on 'use strict mode' declaring a const will work but the export will fail.

Comment: `export` implies a module which implies strict mode.